# What is the quote function in UniswapV2Library used for?

Tags: solidity, uniswap, amm

[image]

What is the purpose of the quote function and how does it differ from getAmountOut?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both functions return the price of asset in an Uniswap pool which has token composition as specified by the `reserveA` and `reserveB` (or `reserveIn` and `reserveOut`) arguments.

The `quote` function returns the price without the swap fee, the  `getAmountOut` function includes swap fee.

According to [the docs](https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v2/reference/smart-contracts/library#quote), `quote` is useful for computing the amounts for minting tokens, `getAmountOut` for trading.